# Set Date in datepicker using javascript for webdriver

Tags: javascript, datepicker, webdriver

How can we set date in date picker using java script for web driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1.

```
  driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('startdate').removeAttribute('readonly')");
  var startDateBox = element(by.id('startdate'));
  startDateBox.clear();
  startDateBox.sendKeys("02/08/2017");
```

2.

```
 browser.driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('startdate').setAttribute('value','02/08/2017')")
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant try this, see if it works for you.

you can enable the date box using javascript & enter the required date

**Code for entering date**

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript ("document.getElementById('your locator').removeAttribute('readonly',0);"); // Enables the from date box

WebElement DateBox= driver.findElement(your locator);
DateBox.clear();
DateBox.sendKeys("8-Dec-2014"); //Enter date in required format
```

Answer (score -1):

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('LOCATOR').value='28/03/2014 12:55';");
```